# AWS Lambda not writing records to AWS Aurora RDS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

My code below does not write anything to the RDS MySql table from lambda. For sure I can say it gets into the if condition as I can see it in CloudWatch and also I dont see any errors as well. It also doesn't print the result as well.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService({ apiVersion: '2018-08-01' });

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var userId;
    var givenName;
    var count = 0;

    var params = {
        secretArn: 'secretArn',
        resourceArn: 'resourceArn',
        database: 'db',
        parameters: [{
                name: "userId",
                value: {
                    "stringValue": userId
                }
            },
            {
                name: "givenName",
                value: {
                    "stringValue": givenName
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    event.Records.forEach(async function (record) {
        count++;
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

        if (record.eventName == 'INSERT') {
            userId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.pk.S;
            givenName = record.dynamodb.NewImage.sk.S;
            console.log('userId - '+userId);
            console.log('givenName - '+givenName);
            params.sql = 'INSERT INTO Users (UserId, GivenName) VALUES(:userId, :givenName);'
            let result = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
            console.log('Result -'+result);
        }

    });
console.log(count);
        return 'done';
    };
```

Here is my CloudWatch log -
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promises in your `forEach` block are being ignored.

I would suggest keeping a list of promises and then awaiting them all.

```js
const promises = event.Records.map(async function (record) {
    count++;
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (record.eventName == 'INSERT') {
        userId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.pk.S;
        givenName = record.dynamodb.NewImage.sk.S;
        console.log('userId - ' + userId);
        console.log('givenName - ' + givenName);
        params.sql = 'INSERT INTO users (userid, givenname) VALUES(:userid, :givenname);'
        let result = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
        console.log('Result -' + result);
    }
});

await Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Thanks Noel, Now I see it is writing data to RDS, Could I ask you to check if I have the right INSERT statement there, as of now it is literally writing userid and givenname as values for the fields. And also cloudwatch says Paramter userId has value with no field set.

Comment: The `params` that you pass to your `RDS.executeStatement(params)` call is incomplete. You have `sql` but you didn't pass `parameters`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDSDataService.html#executeStatement-property.